# how to wrap command with many quotes into watch properly?

Tags: bash, watch

I have such a bash command ...

`psql -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname LIKE 'efa%' OR datname LIKE 'geocms%';"`

and am wondering how to wrap this into `watch -cd "<command>"` properly. The excess of quotes is to be avoided.

tried those 2 without success

```
watch -cd `psql -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname LIKE 'efa%';"`
watch -cd "psql -c \"SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname LIKE 'efa%';\""
```

**EDIT:**

escaping excess `"` with `\"`works actually:

`watch -cd "psql -c \"SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname LIKE 'efa%';\""`

Comment: I can see why your first attempt fails, but what happens when you try the last variation? Do you get any error messages at all? What does "without success" actually mean?

Comment: Your last suggestion (or a very close approximation to it) runs for me

Comment: sorry, you ar right the second version works. I just did not look at it correctly somehow. Sorry, for the false alarm